# Rooted Nexus 7 v2: Using Tor and Adblock Plus

Tags: root-access, nexus-7, stock-android, tor, adblock-plus

I'm having success using both Tor and Adblock Plus, although independently.  I'm trying to figure out how to get both to work on the device at the same time.

When successfully using Tor, I get ads yet adblock works when Tor is disabled.

Adblock Plus 1.2.1 build 318

Android build KTU84L

Orbot 13.0.7-BETA-1

My question is, have any of you been able to get the two to cooperate and if so, how?

Comment: Since both work by acting as proxy server, it's no surprise they'd interfere with each other. You might have better luck using a different ad-blocker that works by editing the hosts file (such as AdAway).

Answer (score 0):

Yes they both use a proxy. Root rqd. Proxies on the wireless nic I believe. They don't interfere with each other. Abp uses port 2020 which I dont think you can configure. So configure tor to use localhost:2020 and if abp is running all good.

Sorry for bad english. Usibg android keyboa rd and no good on them.

Part axe.